# In need for a site that explains how to use PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

I am searching for a tutorial `(optimally with Zend Framework)` on how to use `PHPUnit`.

I have found a couple on `google` but have not quiet understood it yet.

Comment: Do you need information on how and why to use unit testing or special information about PHPUnit in combination with Zend Framework?

Comment: Beyond whatever you get here (hangy provided all useful pointers), subscribe to some of the ZF mailinglists (e.g. fw-general), they are very helpful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What your are looking for is the [Pocket Guide](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/). It explaines how to work with PHPUnit from A to Z in several languages. You can read it online or offline, for free, and it's regularly updated.

Comment: Honestly, if thats all there is for a newcomer to PHP unit testing I can understand why so many people don't write any unit tests at all. This may be the reference manual but it is about as friendly as a block good old german Krupp Stahl. Thanks for sharing the link anyway.

Answer (score 7):

For information about [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/), be sure to read the [documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.3/en/). It does not look too bad IMO. There is a blog entry about [Automatic testing of MVC applications created with Zend Framework](http://replay.waybackmachine.org/20090426040436/http://www.alexatnet.com/node/12) which looks quite good, too. :)

Comment: currently points to: "Using Virtual PC for running Windows Vista"

Comment: Seems like the original link is now dead (and unfortunately even reused). I replaced it with one to the Internet Archive.

Answer (score 4):

There is also an "[Introduction to the Art of Unit Testing](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2772-An-Introduction-to-the-Art-of-Unit-Testing-in-PHP)" posted on the Zend Developer Zone, which covers PHPUnit with Zend specifically.

Answer (score 2):

[Simpletest](http://simpletest.org/), which is very similar to PHPUnit, but a lot simpler, has a good [introductory tutorial](http://simpletest.org/en/first_test_tutorial.html). Even if you plan to use PHPUnit, this should teach you the basics of unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a simple introduction to using PHPUnit and `Zend_Test` with the Zend Framework, I wrote a [simple tutorial that covers the basics of setting up PHPUnit](http://blog.andrewhavens.com/2009/03/getting-started-with-zend_test-step-3-make-sure-phpunit-is-ready-for-testing/) and writing a few simple tests both with PHPUnit and `Zend_Test`.

Answer (score 0):

A great tutorial (git-based, exercise based), on physically going through the motions of testing by Sebastian Marek: https://github.com/proofek/phpnw12-tutorial

Found it very helpful for very baseline beginners. The slides:
http://www.slideshare.net/proofek/test-your-code-like-a-pro-phpunit-in-practice