# Testing PHP code

Tags: php, unit-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In need for a site that explains how to use PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110858/in-need-for-a-site-that-explains-how-to-use-phpunit)

Hi guys.

I want to have a better testing procedure when I develop my applications in PHP.

At the moment I map out all the possible actions/pages in my applications and test them all out everytime I make changes - that is in a perfect world. Often Time issues prevents me for test everything everywhere and bugs do happen. Of course they will always happen but I would like to reduce the amount of bugs.

I'm still trying to understand how unit testing works. The tutorials I found was more like intermediate/expert guides

- Do you have some links to newbie tutorials for Unit testing?
- How do you setup a effective testing procedure?

Answer (score 3):

I've had good results with [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/) and the getting started information (directly available on the home page) should guide you through things nicely.

Comment: +1 because PHPUnit is the de-facto standard for UnitTests in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleTest (Unit Testing for PHP)

http://simpletest.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to browse your website automatically. It supports assertions so that you can create tests and notice when something is broken.